# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all' when searching for a smaller image within a screenshot

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

Using this function, I am trying to find the location of a smaller image that is certainly in a screenshot.

```
screen = ImageGrab.grab()
screen.save(save_path)  #Saves to project's folder as 'screenshot.png'

im_haystack = Image.open('screenshot.png')
im_needle = Image.open('smaller_image.png')

def find_matches(haystack, needle):
    arr_h = np.asarray(haystack)
    arr_n = np.asarray(needle)
    print(arr_h, "Haystack")
    print(arr_n, "Needle")

    y_h, x_h = arr_h.shape[:2]
    y_n, x_n = arr_n.shape[:2]

    xstop = x_h - x_n + 1
    ystop = y_h - y_n + 1

    matches = []
    for xmin in range(0, xstop):
        for ymin in range(0, ystop):
            xmax = xmin + x_n
            ymax = ymin + y_n

            arr_s = arr_h[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]     
            arr_t = (arr_s == arr_n)                
            if arr_t.all():                         
                matches.append((xmin,ymin))
return matches

print(find_matches(im_haystack, im_needle)
```

Using two manually saved images (locating a cropped portion of an image within the original image), this function works properly in finding the image. However, locating a specific image within a screenshot captured and saved with ImageGrab produces this error:

```
line 46, in find_matches
if arr_t.all():                    
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Why is this occurring? What differentiates an ImageGrab screenshot saved as a png from an image taken using snipping tool saved as a png that would cause this?

Comment: what're the shapes of `im_haystack` and `im_needle`?

Comment: What are the values of `x_n` and `y_n`? It looks like the problem is that `arr_s` and `arr_t` are numbers, not arrays.

Comment: @kmario23, haystack is (700,920,3), and needle is (113,299,4), I assume this is what you want?

Comment: @Batman x_n is 299, y_n is 118.

Comment: Ah, I think it is the different colour depths. When comparing two arrays of shapes that cannot be broadcast together `numpy` appears to just return `False` (for example `np.zeros((4,5,3))==np.zeros((4,5,4))` returns `False`), which not being an array doesn't have an `.all` method.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I see. I suppose I'll have to look for a way to convert it, then. A BGR to RGB conversion, I believe. Thanks.

Comment: @ShawnCole22 That is indeed trivial!

Comment: @PaulPanzer `not broadcastable` is the problem and keyword for spotting the error!